# Fortis Dynamic Placeholder Not Working Outside of Experience Editor

Tags: dynamic-placeholder, fortis

I am trying to use Dynamic Placeholders with Sitecore 8.2. I am leveraging http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/dynamic-placeholders/

When adding two renderings with a dynamic placeholder and adding a Content Block in the top placeholder and a Content Block in the bottom placeholder things look fine in Edit or Preview but in Normal mode or viewing the live site after a publish shows the Top Content Block in both placeholders.

Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check your logs on errors? Did you install the library on your cd as well?

Comment: Do you have caching turned on for your rendering that contains the dynamic placeholders?

Comment: I think caching is it, thanks Richard. I turned off all caching at the rendering level but I added a datetime.now at the top and bottom of the rendering with a 2 second sleep and the time is the same on both renderings. So now I just need to figure out where in the pipeline this rendering is getting cached.

Comment: Found the caching issue and it is confirmed. Although my rendering didn't have the cache set, the surrounding rendering did. Not sure how to mark your comment as the answer Richard, but thanks again for the help.